# pg_settings.statement_timeout changing constantly between 0 and 30000?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, timeout

When I run the following query constantly every few seconds over a 30 second time period, I sometimes get a value of 0 and other times a value of 30000.

The value changes constantly and I don't know why.

Can someone give me hints what to look for?

```
SELECT now(), name, setting, unit
FROM   pg_settings
WHERE  name = 'statement_timeout';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your pgbouncer is not configured correctly.  Specifically, `server_reset_query` is not firing, or is set to something that doesn't actually reset enough stuff.  So you find the setting to be whatever was leftover from some previous session you shared the underlying connection with.

Comment: jjanes, Actually, our calls are all of type "Transaction pooling" which I think it might cause the statement_timeout value to not be reset to the value once the connection get back into the pool.  Not sure it is what you meant to look at however.

Comment: were you able to find a solution ?